# How do I use curl to download content from sourceforge?

Tags: curl

Simply typing http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/romfs/genromfs/0.5.2/genromfs-0.5.2.tar.gz works fine on a browser, but I'm trying to download from a CLI environment with limited utilities.

The following just returns an empty file:

```
curl http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/romfs/genromfs/0.5.2/genromfs-0.5.2.tar.gz
```

How do I get genromfs-0.5.2.tar.gz from sourceforge using curl?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can do

```
curl -L  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/romfs/genromfs/0.5.2/genromfs-0.5.2.tar.gz > genromfs.tar.gz
```

to download the file.

The -L tells `curl` to follow any redirects, which sourceforge normally does.

If `wget` is available, that would be far simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately wget wasn't available by default in the live CD I am using.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use `-L` option, because sourceforge uses redirects to the download location. Try `-v` switch and you will see headers of requests and answers.

Answer (score 2):

http://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/rsync/ describes how **project owners** can use `rsync` to download files.

For example, to download all files from https://sourceforge.net/projects/dvn/files/ I used this:

```
rsync -avP -e ssh pdurbin,dvn@frs.sourceforge.net:/home/frs/project/d/dv/dvn/ .
```