# How do I download from SourceForge with wget?

Tags: wget

This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31821/how-do-i-use-curl-to-download-content-from-sourceforge) explains how to do it with `curl`. The accepted answer also points out that

> If wget is available, that would be far simpler.

I looked through `man wget` but the got lost in there, and didn't find an option to follow redirects.

Comment: you mean `man wget`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

wget follows redirects automatically. Just give the URL as an argument

```
wget 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/romfs/genromfs/0.5.2/genromfs-0.5.2.tar.gz'
```

Comment: Oh. I had given it the wrong url and wandering why it is not working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sourceforge URL's often need to be quoted due to the `&`'s in them as well (pre redirect)

Comment: Note that when using `wget` with the SourceForge download URL, the `wget` output shows the `Location:` header containing the "real" URL to which the HTTP GET operation is redirected. Copy this URL for subsequent use with HTTP GET agents that cannot follow redirects.

Comment: this does not work anymore: executing your command ends up with a  `download?use_mirror=vorboss.html` file. What is the solution now?

Comment: Doesn't work, HTML is downloaded: ```wget "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/romfs/genromfs/0.5.2/genromfs-0.5.2.tar.gz"
.... 
Length: 83592 (82K) [text/html]
....````

Comment: You have a %22 (") at the end of the URL. I had no problems with `wget 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/romfs/genromfs/0.5.2/genromfs-0.5.2.tar.gz'`

Comment: @DavidPortabella It's still working.

Answer (score 9):

Start the download in chrome browser. When it starts cancel it and go to downloads page. You can see the url for the download. Copy it and use it with wget.

Comment: This seems to be unnecessarily complicated.  Note that some systems don't have Chrome installed.  Is there any reason why your answer would be preferable over the two-year-old one?

Comment: Aptly said about chrome. I was just trying to provide a simple trick that might be useful for other sites as well.

Comment: Works in Firefox as well.

Comment: Why "chrome browser"? BTW, this is not convenient for using in a command line environment. Normally, people who use wget are not in a graphical environment.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this trick - I was struggling with getting the actual download URL to used when downloading programmatically.

Answer (score 7):

Click the link, you'll get redirected, and you'll see something like "Redirecting... if you are not automatically redirected, click the [direct link](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.99/lame-3.99.5.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Flame%2Ffiles%2Flame%2F3.99%2F&ts=1447772590&use_mirror=skylineservers).

Copy that [direct] link's location, paste it in the command-line like this

```
wget "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lame/lame/3.99/lame-3.99.5.tar.gz"
```

That's it! It worked for me.

Edit: You should omit everything after the '?' character in the url, or else the filename will also have this part.

Comment: Doesn't `wget` automatically follow redirects for you?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev it would, if it were a proper 301/302 redirect. This is a landing page followed by a scripted redirect.

Comment: Thanks, your post solved my annoying problem. In current sourceforge download
page, "direct link" is show if you click the "Problems Downloading?" button.