# wget from Source Forge

Tags: wget, cluster

I know this has been asked here:
[How do I download from SourceForge with wget?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86971/how-do-i-download-from-sourceforge-with-wget/239059#239059)

But I can't get it to work with my specific tool.

Can anyone help me download from this sourceforge link:

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/skewer/

using `wget` I'm trying to install this on a cluster and cannot for the life of me get a download link to work. I keep trying variations of the following:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/skewer/files/latest/download/benchmark1-arabidopsis.thaliana-scripts.tar.gz
```

But all that I keep getting is just an html file or some other stuff

Comment: hope you not just trying to increase downloads XD

Answer (score 1):

It works fine using the direct download, you can also rename file with `-O` parameter

```
wget 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/skewer/Binaries/skewer-0.1.127-linux-x86_64?r=&ts=1445976044&use_mirror=netix' -O skewer-0.1.127-linux-x86_64
```

Comment: But when I do this it still isn't downloading the directory that contains the actual scripts. It just downloads an unreadable file. Were you able to download the actual directory? Thanks.

Comment: it is not a directory, it is an executable. And I obtain the same file too if I download it "manually", and too if I use the above wget command. The executable have the same size, and approximatively, the same content. Then for me the command works well.